# Redux store having multiple 'version' of states under reducer names

Tags: redux, react-redux

I was trying to have separated reducer files for each container file I have, resulting in different reducer exports for each container and I combine it with `combineReducers`.

I want my store to have state that structured like so:

```
state = {
      currentFilter: 'all',
      todos: [],
      displayed: [],
    }
```

But instead get a structure like this:

```
state = {
      addReducer: {
        currentFilter: 'all',
        todos: [],
        displayed: [],
      },
      displayReducer: {
        currentFilter: 'all',
        todos: [],
        displayed: [],
      },
      filterReducer: {
        currentFilter: 'all',
        todos: [],
        displayed: [],
      }
    }
```

the way I create the store:

```
const store = createStore(
      combineReducers({addReducer, displayReducer, filterReducer}),
      applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
    );
```

The problem is when an action got dispatched, the state 'slice' that got updated is only the part associated with the reducer handling that action (in this case below, only the slice on `addReducer` got updated.

The way I write my reducers is only exporting 1 `reduce` function for each reducer file.

Is there any workaround to handle this, or a better and more correct way to deal with multiple reducers, so that the 'single source of truth' concept really happens on my Redux store(instead of different source for different reducer)? Thanks!

EDIT: one of my reducers(the other two are very similar to this one, accepting only 1 switch case and a default case)

```
export default function reduce(state = initialState, action) {  
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_TODO:
      let newTodos = [...state.todos, action.data.todo];
      let newDisplayed = [...state.displayed];
      if (state.currentFilter !== 'completed') {
        newDisplayed.push(action.data.todo);
      }
      console.log(Object.assign(
        {},
        state,
        {
          todos: newTodos,
          displayed: newDisplayed,
        }
      ));
      console.log('newTodos:', action.data.todo);
      return Object.assign(
        {},
        state,
        {
          todos: newTodos,
          displayed: newDisplayed,
        }
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you please post the code for one of your reducers, for instance the "addReducer", thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have edited the question and added one of my reducers, which is the `addReducer` one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing things, you should only have one reducer not three (in your scenario). You should create different reducers to manage different portions of the state, you shouldn't create different reducers about the same portion of the state just addressing different functionalities. You have action creators for it.

You are breaking the "single source of truth" principle from the beginning. So my suggestion is to have one reducer only in your case.

See the docs for more about this with good examples. [LINK](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers)

Just the naming suggests confusion, you should have a `todoReducer` which is associated with the `todo` resource in your app. The `addReducer` is associated with a type of action same for the other two, which is not what you want to do.

I hope this clarifies things a bit but when in doubt check the redux docs they are pretty great!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, ah I get it that a reducer managed a slice of the state, thanks for clearing up the confusion, one little curiosity though, is the combineReducer function that is causing the app state to have names of the reducers? Or it is just the nature of reducers, forming the app state by its name?

Comment: I think that if I write it like this `combineReducers({addReducer: addReducer, displayReducer: displayReducer, filterReducer: filterReducer })`, it will make more sense.

Comment: You could give it any name, since it's just an object and in this case it was just a shorthand. You could have done `combineReducers({coolReducer: addReducer, fancyReducer: displayReducer, funnyReducer: filterReducer })`